# Paypal Parse Java.Lang.Object to PaymentConfirmation in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, paypal, casting, xamarin

I am building a mobile app for android with Xamarin and I want to use paypal for the user to pay us. After the payment I want to sent the confirmation to our server to check that the payment is good and complet and made the modification relating to the purchased.

I used the Android SDK to create a Java Binding Library. I used the tutorial at: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md

```
PaymentConfirmation confirm = 
    data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
```

I turned it into C# as so:

```
PaymentConfirmation confirm = 
    data.GetParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.ExtraResultConfirmation);
```

This give me an exception saying that there exist an explicit cast so I add it:

```
PaymentConfirmation confirm = 
   (PaymentConfirmation)data.GetParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.ExtraResultConfirmation)
```

This gives the following exception: `System.InvaliCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.`

I have tried all I could think of so I'm looking for help.

A functional partial project may be found here:
https://github.com/PhilSim22/PartialProject/tree/master

I am under a nondisclosure agreement so everything not related to the issue have been stripped out. sorry for the inconveniant.

Comment: Shouldn't `EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION` remain unchanged in Xamarin?  Maybe check that the extra exists, extract it, and check what class the object is.

Comment: In Xamarin, EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION does not exist. The Java code is transformed to become C# so I assumed that ExtraResultConfirmation was the same thing.

I saved it as a Java.Lang.Object to make sure it existed and I get this:{com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation@42ec5558} Java.Lang.Object

(the number after the @ changes everytime.) 

com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation does not exist in my context but Com.Paypal.Android.Sdk.Payments.PaymentConfirmation does.

Could that be the probleme and if so how can I fix it?

Comment: Could be.  Maybe you could edit the question to include a reproducible sample app, so others can jump in and help debug.  :)

Comment: Since I am not able to fix this issue and no one seem to be, does anyone have some sort of work around? Other good payment service maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to use a JAVA cast instead of a normal cast. here is my solution:

```
            var confirmObj = data.GetParcelableExtra (PaymentActivity.ExtraResultConfirmation);
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast<PaymentConfirmation> (confirmObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

im you don't find the solution maybe the component parse.com can help you:
https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-with-third-party-services

Comment: no I don'T use Parse. I mean I can't parse(interprete an object into as another object) the Java.Lang.Object returned by the function data.GetParcelableExtra into a PaymentConfirmation object.

Sorry for the unclarity

Answer (score 0):

With any invalid cast exception, the first thing I would try would be to store the result you wish to cast into a temporary variable, and look at its type, either in Debug mode or through logging.

Therefore I would do something like this:

```
object temp = data.GetParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.ExtraResultConfirmation);
Console.WriteLine(temp.GetType().FullName);
Console.WriteLine("Can Assign: {0}", typeof(PaymentConfirmation).IsAssignableFrom(temp.GetType()));
```

This way, you could see if the returned type matches the casted type PaymentConfirmation.

Can you share the full class name of the source and destination classes?

Comment: Full class name: Java.Lang.Object
Can Assign: False